# Json schema regex

Tags: json, regex

I am building a json request schema at the moment. One of my constraints in the schema is that there value of `firstLetter` should ONLY contain 1 character, lowercase or uppercase. I tried the following (its a snippet of the schema):

```
"firstLetter": {
        "id": "/properties/firstLetter",
        "maxLength": 1,
        "minLength": 1,
        "pattern": "[a-z][A-Z]",
        "type": "string"
    }
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I would also like the regex to have the rule that there should only be 1 character

Comment: Try `"^[a-zA-Z]$"` or (if it is used in XSD Schema later) `"[a-zA-Z]"`

Comment: Or use `[a-zA-Z]{1}` it matches a single character.

Comment: @lualover, did my answer work for you? If yes, please consider accepting. Else, please let know of the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acc. to [*6.8. pattern* section of *JSON Schema Validation: A Vocabulary for Structural Validation of JSON*](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.8):

> The value of this keyword MUST be a string. This string SHOULD be a valid regular expression, according to the ECMA 262 regular expression dialect.
>
> A string instance is considered valid if the regular expression matches the instance successfully. Recall: regular expressions are not implicitly anchored.

You may use

```
"pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]$"
```

It will match exactly 1-letter strings, only consisting of an ASCII letter.

Note that `maxLength` and `minLength`  become redundant with this regex validation, so you may minify the code to

```
"firstLetter": {
    "id": "/properties/firstLetter",
    "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]$",
    "type": "string"
}
```

Comment: So would the schema throw a validation error if for example someone sent a request like `"firstLetter":"ab"`

Comment: I updated the pattern as per [this  JSON Schema 1.0 documentation](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html) and [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/example2.html).

Comment: Now, I think it is complete. Sorry, I just mistook the JSON schema with XML Schema at first.